# PhpStorm Emmet - можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы у тегов img, input и тп автоматически выставлялся слэш для закрытия?

Tags: phpstorm

По умолчанию когда я пишу input, например. И жму Tab. Пишется вот такое:

```
<input type="text">
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы добавлялся закрывающий слэш:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По спецификации, для [void](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) элементов типа `<input>` закрывающий `/` не нужен.
Но Вы можете поменять текущее поведение, отредактировав соответствующим образом  шаблон `input` в **Settings | Editor | Live Template | Zen Html**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. А вы не могли бы ответить на этот вопрос? 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811154/phpstorm-file-watcher-sass-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-8-10-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C