# PhpStorm File watcher SASS очень медленно работает (8-10 секунд). Как ускорить?

Tags: phpstorm

Если я открою в PhpStorm `.sass` файл. Напечатаю пробел, например. Появляется внизу надпись: `Executing 'SCSS' Task...` и длится около 8-10 секунд. Если компилировать тот же самый sass файл через `compass watch scss/main.scss` то все происходит быстрее - секунды за 2. 
Как можно ускорить компиляцию sass файла в PhpStorm? Я видел этот вопрос на английском stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913744/scss-filewacher-compiler-takes-far-too-long-to-execute-in-phpstorm), но там для MacOS, а у меня Windows 10.

Если что, вот настройки SASS File Watcher'а: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать убрать `--no-cache` из аргументов - кеширование сильно ускоряет повторную компиляцию (https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/ispolzovanie_sass/keshirovanie.html)